# C# & Javascript DES encryption return different results

Tags: javascript, c#, node.js, encryption

I have this legacy C# code that I need to move to Javascript:

```
var strToBase64 = ClsMyClass.EncryptDES("123456789101112", "12345678");

private static byte[] Keys = new byte[8]
        {
      (byte) 18,
      (byte) 52,
      (byte) 86,
      (byte) 120,
      (byte) 144,
      (byte) 171,
      (byte) 205,
      (byte) 239
        };

public static string EncryptDES(string encryptString, string encryptKey)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptKey);
        byte[] keys = ClsSecurity.Keys;
        byte[] bytes2 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encryptString);
        DESCryptoServiceProvider cryptoServiceProvider = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(
             (Stream)memoryStream,
             cryptoServiceProvider.CreateEncryptor(bytes1, keys),
             CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        cryptoStream.Write(bytes2, 0, bytes2.Length);
        cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
        return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
    catch
    {
        return encryptString;
    }
}
```

I cannot just replicate the results in NodeJS.

So far, I'm using CryptoJS to achieve this. Unsuccessfully. Hope somebody can give me a hand with this.

```
var CryptoJS = require('crypto-js');
var Keys = new Uint8Array(8);
Keys[0] =18;
Keys[1] =52;
Keys[2] =86;
Keys[3] =120;
Keys[4] =144;
Keys[5] =171;
Keys[6] =205;
Keys[7] =239;

var bytes1 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('12345678');
var keys = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(Keys);
var bytes2 = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('123456789101112');

var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(
    bytes1, keys, 
    { 
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, 
        iv: bytes2, 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  
    });

var result = encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

**C# code returns "u2MnJk8fY2G9fbf0xiDACg=="**

JS code returns "0D3HZLzS736SesFr1OZl0g=="

Mode and padding are double-checked ok.
Hope someone can help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, DES is badly broken at this point.

Comment: Utf8 and have nothing to do with each other. `CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse` expects a string, not an array. You need to find another way to provide this IV to CryptoJS (don't use the name `keys` if it is supposed to be the IV judging by the legacy code).

Comment: Thanks @EJoshuaS for your response. I know about DES condition, but since this encryption goes into a .exe application, I need to replicate it AS-IS.

Comment: Thanks @ArtjomB. for your response. You are right about it. I have just posted a working solution from node.js that completely uses another way for doing this.

To be honest, I know nothing about encryption, know nothing about C# but made my way to solve this googling it all, many times, different search terms, etc.

In regards to the "security" it provides, I'm not doing it for it, I just need to replicate the exact same info that will be sent to an .exe application.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I found and solved the problem.

```
function encodeDesCBC(textToEncode, keyString, ivString) {
    var key = new Buffer(keyString.substring(0, 8), 'utf8');
    var iv = new Buffer(ivString.substring(0,8), 'utf8');
    var cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('des-cbc', key, iv);
    var c = cipher.update(textToEncode, 'utf8', 'base64');
    c += cipher.final('base64');
    return c;
  }
```

Comment: Tell what the fix is in words, not just a bunch of code. The answer needs to be useful to future viewers.

Comment: Well, actually is a whole different approach here. Since what I was trying to achieve from legacy code have a text to encode, a key and an initial vector, first approach does not handles those 3 elements as C# does ( C# and CryptoJS use different bit-size by default) 

This different approach from nodejs does. However, I believe that this "bunch of code" explains by itself. If you want to replicate in JS what System.Security.Cryptography does in C# you can do it with this code.

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript code is using the message as the IV, the IV as the key, and the key as the message. Try:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.DES.encrypt(
    bytes2, bytes1, 
    { 
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, 
        iv: keys, 
        padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7  
    });
```

And if that works, rename your variables to be meaningful and avoid this confusion!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will change var names to a meaningful name (just trying to follow as close as possible from legacy c# code)

I did the change you suggested and now I'm getting "dOSkhqSQ4SmJUYFQ4jDifA==" as a result, which still is different from original C# execution.